# IF statement. Run function if data is listed in variable

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get value from Google Spreadsheet. I'm looping through each column to get the values and want to set condition if the value in the column is 1 or 8 or 15 or 22, 29,....... (number increasing by 7 starting from 1 until 365), the code will run, else it will not run.

First I trying with while loop for increment.

```
var data = 1;
 while(data < 365){
 data += 7;
 Logger.log(data); //data 1,8,15,22,29
```

So now I want to compare above data with my next condition which is getCol condition.
So every time var "data" numbers is same like the var "getCol" numbers, the code will run.

```
function runCode(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetByName("Data");
var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();

 for(var x=11; x<ss.getLastColumn(); x++){
 var getCol = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(),x).getValue(); //value=6,7,8,9,10,11,12........
   
    if(getCol === ""){
          false;

        }else if(getCol === 8 || getCol === 15){
          ssRota.getRange(ldap,getCol).setValue("Test");

        }
        else{
          ssRota.getRange(ldap,getCol).setValue("Input");
}
```

As you can see, I'm currently using the OR statement. If the values are 8 or 15, the code will run and set the value in each column to "Test". But now it will be insane if I want to write OR statement 8,15,22,29...... until 365.
I'm trying with

```
else if(getCol === data){
 console.log("same");
}
```

but seem like it didn't work. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
else if(getCol === 8 || getCol === 15){
```

you can try this

```
else if(getCol % 7 === 1){
```

Comment: wow! nice thinking. It's worked perfect. Thanks a lot man